# get no output from .csv parser

Tags: c++, csv

The following code is supposed to take in a filename, i.e. "example.csv", and output a 2D array.

```
typedef vector<vector<double> > matrix;

matrix importcsv(string filename)
{
    ifstream myfile (filename);
    matrix contents {{0.0}}; 
    char parens; double data; int i,j;
    while(!myfile.eof())
    {
        if(myfile.get()==',')
        {
            ++j; 
            contents[i].resize(j+1); 
            myfile >> parens;
        }
        else if(myfile.get()=='\n')
        {
            ++i; 
            contents.resize(i+1);
            j=0; 
            contents[i].resize(j+1);
        }
        else
        {
            myfile >> data; 
            contents[i][j]=data;
        }
    }
    return contents;
}
```

THE ISSUE: The compiler runs smoothly, but the executable returns nothing.

When I write out the loop by hand, i.e. via repeating the code manually with Ctrl+V, the function works as expected. So the error must be somewhere in the 'if' or 'else if' syntax...

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? Like adding breakpoints (or cout messages like "I got this far") to see if the code gets executed?

Comment: `The compiler runs smoothly, but the executable returns nothing.`  What do you mean by "the compiler runs smoothly"?  It's supposed to "run smoothly", else you couldn't produce an executable file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I know what the problem is. In your if statements, `myfile.get()` actually reads a character, not just verifies what the next character is.

So if the next character is a new line, the first if statement will get it, but will be false, the second if also won't be true since the previous if already ate the new-line character.

Do something like:

```
    char c = myfile.get();
    if(c == ',')
    {
        ++j; 
        contents[i].resize(j+1); 
        myfile >> parens;
    }
    else if(c=='\n')
    {
        ++i; 
        contents.resize(i+1);
        j=0; 
        contents[i].resize(j+1);
    }
    else
    {
        myfile >> data; 
        contents[i][j]=data;
    }
```

Comment: ah - insightful! I was struggling for intuition with what the myfile.get() function actually does

Comment: There's a really good documentation over at cplusplus.com. I use it for everything. Here's the documentation for `get` function: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/